# Gitlab CI include not merge correctly

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

Hi guys assume this is my gitlab ci

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - install
  - build
  


before_script:
  - nvm install 14.17
  - nvm use 14.17
  - npm install -g yarn@1.10.1 --registry=$NPM_REGISTRY
  - npm install -g semantic-release
  - git fetch --all

include: '/ci/install_stage.yml'
include: '/ci/build_stage.yml'
```

**/ci/install_stage.yml**

```
install:
  stage: install
  tags:
    - fe
    - xdev
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  only:
    changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      - package.json
      - packages/**/*
  script:
    - yarn install
  cache:
    key: '$CI_PROJECT_PATH-package'
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/
```

**/ci/build_stage.yml**

```
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - fe
    - xdev
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist
  only:
    changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      - package.json
      - packages/**/*
  script:
    - yarn build
  dependencies:
    - install
  cache:
    key: '$CI_PROJECT_PATH-CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-build'
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist
```

So basically i want to only run `build` after `install`, thats why i put a `dependencies` in `build` job. But then the lint give me error `build job undefined dependency install`

So it seem the lint of Gitlab is done invidually before the merge ?

anyway to fix this ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `include` [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) :

> The include files are:
>
> - Merged with those in the .gitlab-ci.yml file.
> - Always evaluated first and then merged with the content of the .gitlab-ci.yml file, regardless of the position of the include
>   keyword.

So you can update your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like this, to evaluate all includes before merging, so the `build` job will know your `install` job :

```
stages:
  - install
  - build

...

include: 
  - '/ci/install_stage.yml'
  - '/ci/build_stage.yml'
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having same problem, the reason is gitlab will overwrite `include` method, therefore, for my case, it only include build but not install stage.

To fix, i changed to an array type
`include: ['/ci/install_stage.yml', '/ci/build_stage.yml']`